# JSONP in non jsonp supported site

Tags: json, jsonp

I have a requirement where I have to get data from another server .. The server supports only JSON and not JSONP. How can I get the data from the server using JSONP?

I am doing it in jquery..

Is there any other solution to it?

Kindly help me..

Answer (score 1):

The reason why JSONP exists is to get around the cross-domain issue with Javascript. This basically means that javascript in your browser shouldn't be allowed to talk to webservices that's not on the same domain as your web application.

JSONP makes this cross-domain integration possible because your browser and the server have an "agreement". You give it a callback, and it gives you the result, wrapped in that callback. It expects to be called via javascript so there's less of a security risk involved.

Example:

```
You call http://www.abccorp.com/index.php?callback=somevalue
```

Without JSONP, you'd get back:
    { some: 'value' }

With JSONP:

```
somevalue({ some: 'value' });
```

**If a server does not support this callback, it's just not possible (by only using javascript).**

I recommend using a server-side programming language that can facilitate this call for you.

For example, you have a PHP file called index.php. Your javascript would call this file using an AJAX JSON request. In turn, it would call the server you need, get the results, and forward them to the javascript. Since you're not using javascript, this server-side programming does not need a callback (or agreement) like javascript does.

Comment: Ok. But I need to understand how phonegap is able to do cross-domain requests? Because it is fully js..

Comment: Please add additional background to your question. It's a bit hard to understand what you're specifically trying to do.